# Synchronous Call in JavaScript is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a hotel page which contains all the details of hotels including its reviews. For the reviews of the hotel, i want to do pagination.

In my code, `init()` function contain all the code for performing initial calculations like calculating no of pages etc.

As you can see `init()` is calling a function `getReviewList` which will return list of reviews. In `getReviewList()`, making a synchronous call to receive lists of reviews(i.e. reviewList.json).

The goal is once i receive the list of reviews, i can perform all the calculations. Even i am using `setTimeout` function so that this action get delayed by some time and in this mean time, the response get stored in the global variable "reviewList".

*But* the problem is that the calculation part gets executed before the response is stored in the global variable "reviewList". Please guide me where i am going wrong.

**Javascript** (fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/n28SS/) *fiddle contains incomplete code*

```
     getReviewList: function () {
        var myReq, reqJSON,
            oThis = this;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            myReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            myReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        myReq.open("GET", "reviewList.json", true);
        myReq.send();
        myReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (myReq.readyState == 4) {
                if (myReq.status == 200) {
                    oThis.reviewList = JSON.parse(myReq.responseText);

                }
            }
        }          
    },                        

    init: function() {
        var oThis = this,
            records;

        records = oThis.getReviewList();
        setTimeout(function () {

            records = oThis.reviewList.length; 
        }, 1000);

        oThis.pages = Math.ceil(records / oThis.itemsPerPage);
        oThis.inited = true;
        oThis.attachEventListener();
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because

```
  setTimeout(function () {

        records = oThis.reviewList.length; 
    }, 1000);
```

returns immediately and performs the records=... operation in the background after 1000 ms.
The following line executes immediately and hence doesn't have access to records variable 
`oThis.pages=Math.ceil(records/...)`

which will become available 1sec later. You can either move all the code into the set timeout block, or better yet make everything asynchronous:

```
 getReviewList: function (callback) {//pass the function that needs to act on list
    var myReq, reqJSON,
        oThis = this;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        myReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        myReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    myReq.open("GET", "reviewList.json", true);
    myReq.send();
    myReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (myReq.readyState == 4) {
            if (myReq.status == 200) {
                oThis.reviewList = JSON.parse(myReq.responseText);
                callback(oThis.reviewList);
            }
        }
    }          
},                        

init: function() {
    var oThis = this,
        records;

    records = oThis.getReviewList(function (reviewList) { //Pass the function as a parameter

        records = reviewList.length; 

    oThis.pages = Math.ceil(records / oThis.itemsPerPage);
    oThis.inited = true;
    oThis.attachEventListener();
    });


},
```

I haven't tested the code but it should demonstrate the basic concept.